# How can I rename a list of files with its folder names

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, tidyverse, lapply

I have a folder containing 5219 scanned jpg-files from an oldschool computer magazine. ("G:\M&K") The files are sorted in folders with years (1979, 1980, ..., 1988) and then in issues (1:6). So the path to my first issue looks like this: "G:\M&K\1979\1".

Filenames are not perfectly structured so I need to rename them by page number, year, and issue. Something like this: [page number]*[issue]*[year].

I have tried:

```
files <- data.frame(list.files("G:/M&K", full.names = T, include.dirs = T, recursive = T, pattern = ".jpg"))
```

But that only gives me a list of file paths and it would require me to filter every single year and issue.

Then I have tried:

```
ordner_liste <- list.dirs("G:/M&K") %>%
  str_subset("/..../.")
filesliste <- rbind.data.frame(
  lapply(
    ordner_liste, function(
      ordner_oeffnen){
  list.files(
    ordner_liste)
}),ordner_liste)
```

But that gives me a weird data frame with 57 columns containing the files from the first folder.

The best case for me would be a data frame with separate columns for year, issue, and filename. Then my next step would be to try to rename all the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's good how you started out. Just use `strsplit` on `files` splitting on the slash `/` and `rbind` the result to a data frame by omitting the unneeded columns.

```
files <- data.frame(V1=list.files("V:/M&K", full.names=T, include.dirs=T, 
                               recursive=T, pattern=".jpg"))


res <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(files$V1, "/"))[-(1:2)],
         c("year", "issue", "file"))
```

**Result**

```
res
#    year issue   file
# 1  1979    01 01.jpg
# 2  1979    01 02.jpg
# 3  1979    01 03.jpg
# 4  1979    02 01.jpg
# 5  1979    02 02.jpg
# 6  1979    02 03.jpg
# 7  1979    03 01.jpg
# 8  1979    03 02.jpg
# 9  1979    03 03.jpg
# 10 1980    01 01.jpg
# 11 1980    01 02.jpg
# 12 1980    01 03.jpg
# 13 1980    02 01.jpg
# 14 1980    02 02.jpg
# 15 1980    02 03.jpg
# 16 1980    03 01.jpg
# 17 1980    03 02.jpg
# 18 1980    03 03.jpg
# 19 1981    01 01.jpg
# 20 1981    01 02.jpg
# 21 1981    01 03.jpg
# 22 1981    02 01.jpg
# 23 1981    02 02.jpg
# 24 1981    02 03.jpg
# 25 1981    03 01.jpg
# 26 1981    03 02.jpg
# 27 1981    03 03.jpg
```

Tested by creating a folder structure according to your description.

Comment: I had to use as.character() on files$V1 but it worked. Thx!

Comment: @NicoSaameli Cool! Yes, that's probably because you have an old R version < 4.0.0 installed, where `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` is standard. You should update.

Comment: Shame on me. I thought nobody ever sees the warnings I get when loading my packages =).